# Exracting Fields from JSON array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-json

My Table

```
create table i (a json)
```

Insert:

```
insert into i values ('[[1300,[{"id":5,"time":1451423706048,"zon":0,"name":"AMighty","loc":"ny"},[[3405,0,1000],[35,0,1000],[3401,0,10000],[2541,0,1000]]]]]' )
```

I wish to extract the field which comes after 2541. in that case the answer 0

When querying my Json with:

```
select json_array_elements(a) from I
```

it returns only one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go through all the nested arrays to get necessary element:

```
WITH i(a) AS ( VALUES
  ('[[1300,[{"id":5,"time":1451423706048,"zon":0,"name":"AMighty","loc":"ny"},[[3405,0,1000],[35,0,1000],[3401,0,10000],[2541,0,1000]]]]]'::JSON)
)
SELECT
  array_element->1->1->3 as array_you_look_for,
  array_element->1->1->3->1 as inner_array_element
FROM i,
  json_array_elements(a) as array_element;
```

Output:

```
 array_you_look_for | inner_array_element 
--------------------+---------------------
 [2541,0,1000]      | 0
(1 row)
```

Comment: can you clarify this syntax: FROM i,  json_array_elements(a) as array_element; what relation is created?

Comment: what do you mean?  after `FROM` clause  you can specify  one or **more** sources to select from - check http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html @koriander

Comment: I'm not familiar with postgresql specifities and that page is not clear on this point, but the comma is usually a cartesian join, so the second part should be a relation. But how come json_array_elements(a) knows it refers to field 'a' of table i.

Comment: and why not simply do SELECT  a->0->1->1->3->1  from i

Comment: Dmitry, Is there is away which I can take the 2541 as a field and not by location?

Comment: @Balinti I'm not sure, what are you referring to ? this specific use case is array `[2541,0,1000]` and you can get values by specifying its index.

Comment: I mean find the array which start with 2541 and return the 2nd place value, without giving the exact location of the array.

Comment: something like select item->1 from i, json_array_elements(a->0->1->1) item where item->0 = 2541;  but it doesn't work in 9.3

Comment: @ Koriander , that is not what I mean, I don't want to check the location and see if its true, I want to find the location just like a key.

Comment: sorry I don't follow you. You have a structured json structure, either you search in the full text or per object field or per position in an array.

Comment: answering to my own question above, functions in the FROM clause always act like correlated suqueries, even without LATERAL.